# EF Core - error with duplicated key while adding data with unique index

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first-mapping

I'm trying to add data to the database using EF Core, but I cannot overcome duplicate key error: `Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Stocks' with unique index 'IX_Stocks_Name'. The duplicate key value is (stock1).`

I have entity `Stock` that has relation one-to-many with `Transaction` - one `Stock` can be related with many `Transaction`s.

The problem doesn't occur only if there's no `Stock` with a given ID in the database - in that case I can add many `Transaction`s with the same `StockID` and it works:

```cs
using(var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(new string[0]))
     {
        List<Transaction> list = new List<Transaction>();
        //If there's no Stock with ID "stock1" in the database the code works.
        //Executing the code for the second time results in error, however, if I changed stock1 to stock2 it would work 
        var stock1 = new Stock("stock1");
        list.AddRange(new Transaction[]
        {
        //I can add two exactly the same `Transaction`s and it's ok when executed on a fresh database
        new Transaction(stock1, DateTime.Now, 1M, 5),
        new Transaction(stock1, DateTime.Now, 1M, 5),
        });
        context.Transactions.AddRange(list);
        context.SaveChanges();
     }
```

Below I added definitions of classes with their `IEntityTypeConfiguration`s.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

`Transaction` class:

```cs
public class Transaction
    {
        public Stock RelatedStock { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionTime { get; set; }
        public Decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Volume { get; set; }
        public Transaction() { }
    }
```

`TransactionConfiguration` class:

```cs
public class TransactionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Transaction>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Transaction> builder)
        {
            builder
                .ToTable("Transactions");

            builder
                .Property<int>("TransactionID")
                .HasColumnType("int")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .HasAnnotation("Key", 0);

            builder
                .Property(transaction => transaction.Price)
                .HasColumnName("Price")
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .Property(transaction => transaction.TransactionTime)
                .HasColumnName("Time")
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .Property(transaction => transaction.Volume)
                .HasColumnName("Volume")
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .HasIndex("RelatedStockStockID", nameof(Transaction.TransactionTime))
                .IsUnique();
        }
    }
```

`Stock` class:

```cs
public class Stock
  {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
     public Stock() { }
  }
```

`StockConfiguration` class:

```cs
public class StockConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Stock>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Stock> builder)
        {
            builder
                .ToTable("Stocks");

            builder
                .Property<int>("StockID")
                .HasColumnType("int")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .HasAnnotation("Key", 0);

            builder
                .Property(stock => stock.Name)
                .HasColumnName("Name")
                .HasMaxLength(25)
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .HasMany(stock => stock.Transactions)
                .WithOne(transaction => transaction.RelatedStock)
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .HasIndex(stock => stock.Name)
                .IsUnique();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a unique index on the `dbo.Stocks` table named `IX_Stocks_Name`.  You're violating this index.

Your problem is this line:

```
var stock1 = new Stock("stock1");
```

You're creating "stock1" over and over.  Instead, you should first be retrieving (or storing) the `Stock` entity for "stock1" and using that, if it already exists.  If it doesn't exist then it's safe to create one.

In short, the code is doing an `INSERT` into `dbo.Stocks` with an existing `Name`.

Comment: As for the line you mentioned - I was creating `Stock` manually for the sake of depicting a problem. Actually, I parse a text file and pass `List<Transaction>` into the function and then call `context.Transactions.AddRange(list)` Of course, every stock is refered by lots of transactions. Could you elaborate a little bit more on a possible approach to solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there is a Stock already known for the desired ID. for the sake of your example:

```
var stock1 = context.Stocks.SingleOrDefault(x => x.StockId == "stock1") ?? new Stock("stock1");
```

This will associate an existing stock if one is already in the database, or associate a new one if there is none.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. To be honest, I would expect Entity Framework to take care of associating entities in such way automatically.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to do that automatically.  Use auto-generated numeric or guid keys to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Zer0's and @Steve Py's suggestions I came up with the following solution:

```cs
void Insert(IEnumerable<Transaction> data)
        {
            using(var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(new string[0]))
            {
                List<Stock> stocks = data.Select(s => s.RelatedStock).Distinct(new StockComparer()).ToList();
                context.AddRange(stocks);
                context.SaveChanges();
                stocks = context.Stocks.ToList();

                List<Transaction> newList = new List<Transaction>(data.Count());

                foreach (var t in data)
                {
                        Stock relatedStock = stocks.Where(s => s.Name == t.RelatedStock.Name).First();
                        t.RelatedStock = relatedStock;
                        newList.Add(t);
                }

                context.Transactions.AddRange(newList);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```